# FreeAgent API (OAuth) From c#

Tags: c#, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect to a API (In this case freeagent) to grab some data. I've used Googles OAuth Playground to generate me a token.

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.freeagent.com/v2/recurring_invoices");

req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_accessToken));

req.ContentType = "application/xml";
req.Accept = "application/xml";
req.Method = "GET";

// and get the response
var resp = req.GetResponse();
var streamIn = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
returnData = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();

return resp;
```

Now I'm loosly trying to conver the following : https://dev.freeagent.com/docs/using_curl

I constantly get a Bad Request HTTP 400 - Anyone have any suggestions on what could be causing this problem?

Comment: It's most likely your token is not accepted. Do you have to do the conversion to a Base-64 string? What if you put in your access-token without conversion?

Comment: It's the same result, even without the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this, is to pass the UserAgent as well.

Example...

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17";
```

Answer (score 2):

I have most of the api working using RestSharp:

https://github.com/nicwise/FreeAgent

I wrote that for my iPhone app, mobileAgent, but it's fairly basic
.NET, so it should work on anything.

My authentication injection code looks very much like yours:

```
protected void SetAuthentication(RestRequest request)
{
  request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +
Client.CurrentAccessToken.access_token);
}
```

Have you run fiddler or something similar to see exactly what is going
over the wire? that often helps.

Comment: Cheers Nic, will check out your project. I've got some more time to look at it and fiddler is my next option. Will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to base64 encode the token, just set the Authorization header to "Bearer " + _accessToken. If this still doesn't work, try using http://httpbin.org/get as the URL to look at your request to see if there are any other possible problems.